# How to create rounded corners by using a custom view in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have seen the first answer in various places, but it is not working for me. [Android: ListView, problem with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647121/android-listview-problem-with-rounded-corners?rq=1)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

**Custom ImageVIEW with Rounded Corners**

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

```
public static final String TAG = "RoundedImageView";
public static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 0;
public static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
private static final ScaleType[] sScaleTypeArray = { ScaleType.MATRIX,
        ScaleType.FIT_XY, ScaleType.FIT_START, ScaleType.FIT_CENTER,
        ScaleType.FIT_END, ScaleType.CENTER, ScaleType.CENTER_CROP,
        ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE };

private int mCornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
private ColorStateList mBorderColor = ColorStateList
        .valueOf(RoundedDrawable.DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
private boolean mOval = false;
private boolean mRoundBackground = false;

private int mResource;
private Drawable mDrawable;
private Drawable mBackgroundDrawable;

private ScaleType mScaleType;

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.RoundedImageView, defStyle, 0);

    int index = a
            .getInt(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_android_scaleType, -1);
    if (index >= 0) {
        setScaleType(sScaleTypeArray[index]);
    }

    mCornerRadius = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.RoundedImageView_corner_radius, -1);
    mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.RoundedImageView_border_width, -1);

    // don't allow negative values for radius and border
    if (mCornerRadius < 0) {
        mCornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    }
    if (mBorderWidth < 0) {
        mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
    }

    mBorderColor = a
            .getColorStateList(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_border_color);
    if (mBorderColor == null) {
        mBorderColor = ColorStateList
                .valueOf(RoundedDrawable.DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    }

    mRoundBackground = a.getBoolean(
            R.styleable.RoundedImageView_round_background, false);
    mOval = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_is_oval, false);

    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();

    a.recycle();
}

@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Return the current scale type in use by this ImageView.
 * 
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ImageView_scaleType
 * @see android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType
 */
@Override
public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return mScaleType;
}

/**
 * Controls how the image should be resized or moved to match the size of
 * this ImageView.
 * 
 * @param scaleType
 *            The desired scaling mode.
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ImageView_scaleType
 */
@Override
public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    if (scaleType == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    if (mScaleType != scaleType) {
        mScaleType = scaleType;

        switch (scaleType) {
        case CENTER:
        case CENTER_CROP:
        case CENTER_INSIDE:
        case FIT_CENTER:
        case FIT_START:
        case FIT_END:
        case FIT_XY:
            super.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            break;
        default:
            super.setScaleType(scaleType);
            break;
        }

        updateDrawableAttrs();
        updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mResource = 0;
    mDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(drawable);
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    mResource = 0;
    mDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromBitmap(bm);
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
}

@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    if (mResource != resId) {
        mResource = resId;
        mDrawable = resolveResource();
        updateDrawableAttrs();
        super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }
}

private Drawable resolveResource() {
    Resources rsrc = getResources();
    if (rsrc == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Drawable d = null;

    if (mResource != 0) {
        try {
            d = rsrc.getDrawable(mResource);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to find resource: " + mResource, e);
            // Don't try again.
            mResource = 0;
        }
    }
    return RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(d);
}

@Override
public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}

private void updateDrawableAttrs() {
    updateAttrs(mDrawable, false);
}

private void updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs() {
    updateAttrs(mBackgroundDrawable, true);
}

private void updateAttrs(Drawable drawable, boolean background) {
    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (drawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
        ((RoundedDrawable) drawable)
                .setScaleType(mScaleType)
                .setCornerRadius(
                        background && !mRoundBackground ? 0 : mCornerRadius)
                .setBorderWidth(
                        background && !mRoundBackground ? 0 : mBorderWidth)
                .setBorderColors(mBorderColor).setOval(mOval);
    } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
        // loop through layers to and set drawable attrs
        LayerDrawable ld = ((LayerDrawable) drawable);
        int layers = ld.getNumberOfLayers();
        for (int i = 0; i < layers; i++) {
            updateAttrs(ld.getDrawable(i), background);
        }
    }
}

@Override
@Deprecated
public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
    mBackgroundDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(background);
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    super.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
}

public int getCornerRadius() {
    return mCornerRadius;
}

public void setCornerRadius(int radius) {
    if (mCornerRadius == radius) {
        return;
    }

    mCornerRadius = radius;
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
}

public int getBorderWidth() {
    return mBorderWidth;
}

public void setBorderWidth(int width) {
    if (mBorderWidth == width) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderWidth = width;
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    invalidate();
}

public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor.getDefaultColor();
}

public void setBorderColor(int color) {
    setBorderColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
}

public ColorStateList getBorderColors() {
    return mBorderColor;
}

public void setBorderColors(ColorStateList colors) {
    if (mBorderColor.equals(colors)) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderColor = (colors != null) ? colors : ColorStateList
            .valueOf(RoundedDrawable.DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
        invalidate();
    }
}

public boolean isOval() {
    return mOval;
}

public void setOval(boolean oval) {
    mOval = oval;
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    invalidate();
}

public boolean isRoundBackground() {
    return mRoundBackground;
}

public void setRoundBackground(boolean roundBackground) {
    if (mRoundBackground == roundBackground) {
        return;
    }

    mRoundBackground = roundBackground;
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawable selector for that . And Modify Rounded Corner Size

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#136BBD"
            android:endColor="#439AEC"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
        <corners
            android:radius="70dp" />
        <padding 
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="20dp"
            android:top="13dp"
            android:bottom="13dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#439AEC"
            android:endColor="#136BBD"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
        <corners
            android:radius="70dp" />
        <padding 
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="20dp"
            android:top="13dp"
            android:bottom="13dp"/>
    </shape>
</item> 
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml in drawable folder of your project and copy the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke android:width="2dp"
     android:color="#999FB6CD"/>
<gradient 
     android:angle="225"
     android:startColor="#cccccc"
     android:endColor="#cccccc"/>
<corners
     android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
     android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
     android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Now set this xml as background of your view as

```
android:background="@drawable/yourxmlname"
```