# How to add rounded corner as a background of Recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a list. And I want to add a background like round corner to it. So the list is like a big card view. How can I implement this just like Google Translate.

The rounded background can scroll as the listview does. **So The shape.xml solution does not works here**.

[image: This is the screenshot of translate.]

Comment: Take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713231/recyclerview-item-separator

Answer (score 18):

use this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/color_white"/>

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/grey_ask"
        />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

increase the *Radius values for more roundness.
add this as backgound to your recylerview

```
android:background="@drawable/nameofxml"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this solution can add a background to the listview. But the background is static. I want the background can scroll as the listview does. So do you have some other ideas?

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean, this background will give your listview(container) rounded corners..isnt that the initial requirement?
this is a shape drawable.

Comment: Yes, but when I scroll this listview, I want the background move as the listview does. It is like a card. But this solution this background just stand there and listview just scroll inside. If you use the translate app, you may understand what I mean. My English is not good, please forgive me. And Thanks for your help.

Comment: @penghaitao You will have to add the border to the item layout of the Recycler view and not the RecylerView itself.

Comment: this does notwork when I set background color to recyclerview items!

Comment: if i make the corners radius as big as 80dp for example, the items will scroll and fade on top of the transparent corners, is there a trick how to make items fade below the background drawable, like if the recyclerview is actually have its corners cut

Answer (score 0):

Put the recyclerview in a cardview, and set the cardview's corner radius.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).